# Newbie needs Excel suggestions with a simple script

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a excel file and I would like to search on a specific column. I would like to know how many times a specific "letter/character" has been used. In my case its the letter "x". So after little research I found that formula:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D48,"FIDELIO")
```

the problem here is, I always get an error message:
[image]

If I write the Code with an " ` " in front like  this:

```
`=COUNTIF(D2:D48,"FIDELIO")
```

excel just writes me the code in excel as a text and not as a code.

Tried to write the Code with an "`" in front like this:

```
`=COUNTIF(D2:D48,"FIDELIO")
```

But then excel just writes me the code as a text and not as a code.
Here is another picture: [image]

Comment: Change the comma into a semi-colon. See if that fixed the issue. Sidenote, but `=COUNTIF(D2:D48,"FIDELIO")` would not really count the times an x occurs. If you'd use `=COUNTIF(D2:D48,"x")` it would return the times one of these cells **equals** an x. If you'd use `=COUNTIF(D2:D48,"*x*")` it would return the count of cells that **contain** at least an x. Technically that would still be different to the times an x could occur in a cell if that is what you meant to count.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. Unfortunately i get the exact same error. I uploaded a new picture with the error message in my first post. Maybe it helps? Thanks

Comment: What is your language? You may also need to use your Excel's version of the english 'COUNTIF()'. For example, if you were to be polish? Then use `=LICZ.JEŻELI(D2:D48;"x")`

Comment: i replaced it with ";" instead of "," and it worked! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

came across this, hope this helps!

### Formula to Count the Number of Occurrences of a Single Character in a Range

```
=SUM(LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,"a","")))
```

Where range is the cell range in question, and "a" is replaced by the character you want to count.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/formulas-to-count-occurrences-in-excel